# Aurelia bindingContext is undefined

Tags: javascript, aurelia, aurelia-templating

I have a component which is shown in a particular view.
I am now taking that component using `<compose>` to show it in a pop-up as well. 
The component has several components within it.
example code would be like this:

````
<div if.bind="something">
     <inner-component if.bind="something else"></inner-component>
 </div>```
````

this is obviously not the actual code, I am just showing how it is set up. The reason being That when I added the outer `if.bind` The bindingContext supposed to be coming in through `bind()` in the inner component is now `undefined`   BUT this is only in the original view of the component, NOT in the new pop-up view.  Before I added the outer `if` it worked fine for the original view (the pop-up view didnt exist yet)
What am I missing?